# Analytic function performance costly

Tags: performance, oracle, analytical

I have a table_A (C1,C2,C3,.....,Cn, datestamp)

Note : Column datestamp is indexed

QRY1

```
select * from 
(select max(datestamp) dates from table_A) t,
table_A
where a.datestamp = t.dates
```

QRY2

```
   select * from (
   select a.* , max (datestamp) over() dates from table_A a))
   where datestamp = dates
```

Explain Paln of QRY1 using indexed scan (execyted in 1 sec)  cost was very less.

But for QRY2 going for full table scan (execyted in 8 sec) cost was very high.

Just wanted to know why analytical function ignores indexes.

Thanks
(I am usig PL/SQL Oracle 10g)

Comment: this is actually an interesting example. if you have an index on dates then the first sub query in QRY1 will probably do a `MIN/MAX` scan (cost of going down the tree, probably ~3), then fetching the row using the same index - one single row. i'm assuming that it's not unique so a range scan (probably cost about ~4) so it's pretty fast. the analytic function on the other hand - probably sort the data which cause a full table scan so it's much more expensive. you should use analytic functions where you use aggregate function on *portions* of the data (the partition by clause).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm):

> Analytic functions compute an aggregate value based on a group of
>   rows. They differ from aggregate functions in that they return
>   multiple rows for each group.
>   ...
>   Analytic functions are the last set
>   of operations performed in a query except for the final ORDER BY
>   clause. All joins and all WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses are
>   completed before the analytic functions are processed.

Your inner select is pulling all rows from your table because it has no `where` clause; since it has to fetch every row the index isn't helpful and it might as well do a full table scan. Using the index on `datestamp` would be worse - it would have to do a full scan of the index and then access every data row anyway, increasing the IO. If you run the inner select on its own you'll see it returns a lot of rows, not just one.

The outer select then matches a specific row (or rows) from the inner one. That comparison can't be pushed into the inner select because of when in the processing the analytic value is calculated.

Comment: Thanks Alex
So you are saying to get latest data from daily transaction table we should go for conventional sub qry concept (QRY 1 in above example) 
Analytical will not work out efficently.

Comment: @Avi - in this scenario, pulling a single record based on an indexed value, then yes, your testing has shown it to be more efficient.